# jquery breaks html source code

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have the following code at the end of my jsp file in a spring project:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></SCRIPT>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("p").html("Hello <b>world!</b>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

When i view this page's source code i get the following:

```
<script src="/webpage/resources/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></body></html></script>
```

So as you can see, there is a body and html inside the script tag, and i have no idea how it got there. Every file is in the right place, i triple checked.

Any ideas?

Update:

This is my whole code, from another page, it also does not work. I get the same issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"     xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags" version="2.2">
        <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" 
        pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"/>
        <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
        omit-xml-declaration="true" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Stuff</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <spring:url value="/stuff.html" var="stuff"/>
        <p><a href="${stuff}">Stuff</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
</jsp:root>
```

If i insert the jquery include before the closing body, i get the same issue. :(

Comment: The script reference to JQuery should always go in the html head tag not in the body so just cut it out of the body and paste in between head tags.

Comment: @smoggers that is not true... in fact most best practice guidelines suggest placing script tags at end of body

Comment: I'm getting my info from http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp which advises within the head?

Comment: @smoggers and that is another validation for http://www.w3fools.com/ . My info comes from numerous sources including Yahoo Yslow, Google developers guide among others. Also there is a big difference between showing it used in the head and saying it *should always be in the head*

Comment: @MichalHainc if i remove all the jsp, i also get the same thing. :(
 If i put it into the head, then all the page disappears. :S

Comment: If i click the button, nothing happens. It is broken before. :(

Comment: Any idea, anybody? I'm really lost here... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the script element within your jsp file's  tag - at the end if you want to, but definitely before the  tag. You probably placed it after the  or  and the browser is probably closing the tag(s) for you.

You might also want to try adding some dummy content after your script tag, just in case you have some other server side parser is trying to close these tags for you.

Comment: I tried to put a dummy h1 tag after it, but it also goes inside the scipt /script tags. :( What do you mean try placing the script element within my jsp file's tag? Could you please give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I meant within the body tag of the jsp

Comment: It's there, it is right before the closing body tag.